# Display data depending on city location using angular JS and nesting it inside a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I am trying to display the users favourite cities current weather, I am able to pull the weather data back to the console by using there favourite city, however I am having trouble displaying it within an `ng-repeat` which i use to display the favourites list.

HTML code

```html
<li ng-repeat="weatherList in weatherLists" class="col-xs-12">
  <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">{{weatherList.place}}</span>
  <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
  </span>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
    <button type="button" name="button" class="deleFav" ng-click="delete(weatherList)">Delete</button>
    <button type="button" name="button" class="getFavWeather" ng-click="getFavWeather(weatherList)">Refresh To Get Update Weather</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" ng-model="weatherList.edit"/>
    <button ng-click="edit(weatherList)">Edit</button>
  </div>
</li>
```

JS code

```js
yApp.controller('favouritesController', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $route, $location) {
  $http({
    method:'GET',
    url:'http://localhost:8080/inter'
  })
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(status)
    console.log(data)
    const newData = data.data
    $rootScope.newData
    console.log(newData)
    $scope.weatherLists = newData
  })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('error')
  })

  $scope.getFavWeather = function(weatherList) {
    console.log(weatherList._id)
    console.log(weatherList.place)
    const GetFav = weatherList.place
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/inter/call/weatherCall/' + GetFav
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(status)
      console.log("------Hello-----")
      console.log(data)
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log('error')
    })
  }
})
```

Object that I want to pull through and display is 
{"status":"success","message":"weather found for some city","data":{"id":2643743,"city":"London","country":"GB","now":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10d"}],"temp":{"day":13.17,"min":10.69,"max":13.56,"night":10.69,"eve":11.87,"morn":13.56}}}

Comment: So what is / isn't happening? Any errors?

Comment: I am about pull the data back to the console however when i try and {{}} use this with in the ng-repeat it display the weather in all the LI's rather than just the city in question

Comment: Have you tried $scope.weatherList.currentWeather = data inside your getFavWeather function so in your view you could do {{weatherList.currentWeather }} ?

Comment: I get this error 'TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentWeather' of undefined'

Comment: are you trying inside your success callback?

Comment: I am yes, i added into the success callback and then added {{weatherList.currentWeather }} this into my HTML code inside the repeat

Comment: can you log weatherList inside your callback?

Comment: Yes i get "Object {_id: "h8s3i73d5z8xtqstfs2oszrgh13b014", place: "London", $$hashKey: "object:5"}", however this not the data that I am trying to display, the data that I want to display is '{"status":"success","message":"weather found for some city","data":{"id":2643743,"city":"London","country":"GB","now":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10d"}],"temp":{"day":13.17,"min":10.69,"max":13.56,"night":10.69,"eve":11.87,"morn":13.56}}}'

Comment: @gurps can you update this data object in the post?

Comment: I have update the post